# Best place to document our C++ code

Tags: c++, doxygen

After having some readings about `Doxygen` I'm a bit confused where to document my variable, function etc. Should it be in the implementation file(source) or in its interface(header file).

What is the best practise regarding that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doxygen comments on declarations or on definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782267/doxygen-comments-on-declarations-or-on-definitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place documentation in your headers. And one very important thing to look out for is to not overdocument. Don't start writing a comment for every single variable and function, especially if all you do is state the obvious. Examples...

This comment below is obvious and unhelpful. All the comment says is perfectly clear just by looking at the function.

```
/**
    This function does stuff with a prime number.  */
void do_stuff(int prime);
```

You should instead document how the function behaves in extreme situations. For example, what does it do if the parameters are wrong? If it returns a pointer, whose responsibility is it to delete the pointer? What other things should programmers keep in mind when using this function? etc.

```
/**
    This function does stuff with a prime number.
    \param prime A prime number. The function must receive only primes, it
    does not check the integer it receives to be prime.
                                                                               */
void do_stuff(int prime);
```

Also, I would advice you only document the *interface* in the header files: don't talk about *how* the function does something, tell only *what* it does. If you want to explain the actual implementation, I'd put some relevant (normal) comments in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

You should aim to document only your header files, although at times it may prove difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend to put the documentation in the header file, and documented it from a user perspective.

In rare situations it may be beneficial to put the comments in the source file (or even in a separate file), for instance if

- the cost of changing a header (in terms of build impact) is huge, and
- you expect (frequent) changes to the documentation, without changing the syntax of the interface; for instance you regularly improve the documentation based on user feedback, or you have a different team of professional writers that write the documentation after the interface is delivered.

There can be other, less strong reasons: some people like comments in the source code, because it keeps the header file small and tidy. Others expect the documentation to be easier to keep up to date if it is close to the actual implementation (with the risk that they documented what the function does instead of how to use it).